# Xcode 5 Round Rect Buttons

Tags: iphone, button, xcode5

I have an app that incorporates many round rect buttons. However, in xcode 5, those dont exist. How do I get the round rect buttons back? They are essential to my app. Now it just is pressable text. What do I do? I am planning on releasing this app later, if that is relevant.

Comment: surprisingly the iOS 7 Maps app has the round rect info button.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

1. Open the storyboard and choose the button you want to change.
2. Open the Identity Inspector in the Utility Panel (right panel, 3rd button on top).
3. Add (+) a new User Defined Runtime Attribute -- Key Path: layer.cornerRadius, Type: Number, Value: {integer}.

The higher the number, the more rounded the corners.  50 is a circle for a standard button (or width/2).  You won't see the change in the storyboard, but it will show at runtime.

[image: Screenshot of added attribute]

Comment: Answers like this is why I love SO. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a similar answer to the one I gave to [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384832/no-round-rect-button-in-xcode-5/18977274#18977274)

-EDIT-
Add: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to the top of your `.h` file.

If you want rounded corners just `ctrl-drag` from the button to your `.h` file, call it something like `roundedButton` and add this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
CALayer *btnLayer = [roundedButton layer];
[btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
```

To make the button white (or any other colour), select the attributes inspector and scroll down to the `View` section, select Background and change it to White:

[image]

Comment: VERY important. this will not work unless you add  #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: thanks, no worries, just took me a sec so i wanted to share. thanks for the harder work:-)

Comment: This can be set entirely in the Storyboard by adding a user-defined runtime attribute with keypath layer.cornerRadius , type Number, value 5 , etc.

Answer (score 3):

Set a background image on your buttons with the desired borders, using a stretchable image.

Check this link for a good example:
[Stretch background image for UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623961/stretch-background-image-for-uibutton)

OR, embrace the new iOS7 UI and scrap the borders ... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Same can achieved by programmatically.where myView is IBOutlet object.

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2.0:**

```
let sampleButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100,100,200,100))
  sampleButton.titleLabel?.text = "SAMPLE"
  sampleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

  //Setting rounded boarder
  sampleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
  sampleButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
  sampleButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

  self.view.addSubview(sampleButton)
```

Answer (score 3):

Click on the **button** you want to get rounded.
Then click on **the Identity** **Inspector** on the right top side.
There You can see **User Defined Runtime Attributes**.
Click on **plus (+)**

[image: see image]

You wont see the changes in **View**. You will see it in **Runtime**

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3: we can added it viewdidload

```
  button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5*button.bounds.size.width
  button.clipsToBounds = true
```