# How to make a border around a letter in UI Button/Text Label?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've tried and its been 40 mins and I still am unable to put a border around the text that appears , it just remains one solid color, BLUE, and I need a black border around the text.

```
[bigButtonHere setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[bigButtonHere.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 2)];
```

How can I do this?

Additional: I need it on the text in the button, so if the text is yellow it must have a black outline around the letter.

Comment: Boarder isn't a word, border is

Comment: well technically boarder is a word it just means "one who boards" as in boarding a plane or a boat

Comment: Yeah, Border thatnks man!

Comment: Here is a few nice ways to add borders to buttons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384832/no-round-rect-button-in-xcode-5/21199231#21199231

Answer (score 2):

Only

```
 bigButtonHere.titleLabel.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(1, 2);
 bigButtonHere.titleLabel.shadowColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

Tested!

Comment: @AlieN I need it in the text of the button

Comment: @Ricky Then show more code, because the code I wrote works for me. Are you using iOS7? I am.

Comment: Ive got the buttons on a View, and an image on the button! not using storyboard

Comment: @AlieN that would destroy the game, its a word game, and some answers and longer than others! what are you talking about!!!