# How to add Button Style by using buttonWithType in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have added the button in storyboard like the following picture:

[image]

I also have added the code in the header file as shown in the following code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Up;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Back;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Left;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Ok;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Right;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *DeviceSelect;

    @end
```

I want to add the style for the `UIButton` in the .m file as shown in the following code:

```
self.Up = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.view addSubview:_Up];
```

But it seems its not working. The `UIButton` didn't change anything.

Did I miss something?

I am new to iOS , Please teach me... Thanks in advance.

Comment: As of the more minimalistic UI delivered in iOS 7, [iOS doesn't really have "round rect" buttons anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384832/no-round-rect-button-in-xcode-5).  They are simply text labels that the user presses.

Comment: But the button didn't change anything whatever I use any style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already added your button in the storyboard file and because you added buttons that way, you **should not** do these two lines of code:

```
self.Up = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.view addSubview:_Up];
```

You can set the button style via the attributes inspector in Xcode's Interface Builder (which you see when editing the storyboard).

It looks like this:

[image: Use Attributes Inspector to set the button type]